# Wordpress - How do i create category/tag/date filters?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, search, filter

I'm attempting to create a 'jobs' page on a wordpress website.
Each job has a Category (eg. Designer), and a tag for location (eg. Australia).

Currently each 'job' is a 'post' in wordpress.  I'm really hoping to provide the ability for users to sort the jobs either by **category**, **tag**, **date**, or a **combination** of 2 or 3.

I've tried a bunch of plugins to no avail, and was wondering if someone could please lend a hand to explain how they may have accomplished this, or help me out in any other way.

Kind regards,
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should create a **custom post type** of 'job' with category, tag and date as **taxonomies**. You can then use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) to display -and sort- job listings. This tutorial should be enough to get you started: http://new2wp.com/pro/wordpress-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies-done-right/